# Can multiple files be moved in as a batch

Tags: vb.net, file, move

I want to move multiple files from one directoy to anoher. I use 'My.Computer.FileSystem.MoveFile' and that works fine but it handles one file at a time. So, for every already existing file in that directory I get a warning (ie. 'File already exists') instead of one warning for the batch. Is it posible to get one warning for all the moved files?

```
       For i = .Items.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1

                Dim map = .Items.Item(i).SubItems(COL_MAP).Text
                Dim bestandHernoemd = .Items.Item(i).SubItems(COL_HERNOEMD).Text
                Dim bestandOrigineel = .Items.Item(i).SubItems(COL_ORIGINEEL).Text

                    Try

                        My.Computer.FileSystem.MoveFile(map & bestandOrigineel, My.Settings.OPTIE_OvernemenStandaardMapNaam & bestandHernoemd, Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.UIOption.AllDialogs, Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.UICancelOption.ThrowException)

                        .Items.RemoveAt(i)                               

                    Catch ex As Exception

                        foutLijst.Add(bestandOrigineel & ": " & ex.Message)

                    End Try
        Next
```

Comment: Use the `MoveFile(SourceFileName, DestFileName, Overwrite)` version of the function. It still only moves one file at a time, but specifying `Overwrite` as `True` will prevent the warning from being displayed at all. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.filesystem.movefile?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't want the files to be overwritten just like that. I need a warning to see if I want to overwrite that file or not.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Either you want a notice for each and every file (to see if that individual file needs to be replaced or not) or you want no warning at all. You can't have one warning for many files if you're wanting to check each file for replacement.

Comment: Yes, this makes sense. And yes you can! Look at how Windows Explorer handles this problem.

Comment: And maybe thats just where the answer lies. I think I have to build my own customized copy-form like this: (http://www.hanssteenhoek.nl/externe_afbeeldingen/Duplicate_files.jpg)

Comment: Yep. You're absolutely free to write your own implementation that handles it just like Windows Explorer does. But that's not the question you asked here; you asked about using `FileSystem.MoveFile`.

Comment: No Ken, I didn't. "Is it posible to get one warning for all the moved files?" is the question.

Answer (score 1):

And if you want to copy files recursively ( all folders, subfolders, files or subfiles ) from one source to destination, you can use the below sub procedure. No Warning applied and shall overwrite the destination.

```
Public Sub CopyDirectory(ByVal sourcePath As String, ByVal destinationPath As String)
   Dim sourceDirectoryInfo As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(sourcePath)
        'If the destination folder doesn't exist then create it'
      If Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(destinationPath) Then
            'Obs, folder doesn't exist, create one please :)'
         System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationPath)
      End If
   Dim fileSystemInfo As System.IO.FileSystemInfo
       For Each fileSystemInfo In sourceDirectoryInfo.GetFileSystemInfos
         Dim destinationFileName As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(destinationPath, fileSystemInfo.Name)
            'Now check whether its a file or a folder and take action accordingly
            If TypeOf fileSystemInfo Is System.IO.FileInfo Then
              System.IO.File.Copy(fileSystemInfo.FullName, destinationFileName, True)
            Else
              ' Recursively call the method to copy all the nested folders
              CopyDirectory(fileSystemInfo.FullName, destinationFileName)
            End If
       Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank  you for your answer. I need that warning to see if a file needs to be replaced or not.